# Videos not playing in WMP if opened from attachment

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-media-player

If I try to open a video sent as an attachment in an email WMP will open but the video will not play.  If I save the video attachment to my hard drive and then open WMP and manually run the video it plays just fine.  How can I get the video to run when I click the attachment from the email without having to save the file first?

I am running Windows 7 with the latest WMP.
Thank you.
Kristen.

Comment: Which email client are you using?  Gmail in a browser?  Microsoft Outlook?

Comment: I'm using Comcast email through IE 9.

Comment: In that case, @Bon Gart is right; the file doesn't exist on your machine until you save it locally. If you wanted to improve this, you could use a mail client like Outlook which would transparently download the attachment for you, and you could launch it right from the email.

Answer (score 1):

Playing a movie that is not stored on your local machine requires it to be streamed from it's remote location.  When you see a video as an attachment in an email, it is not stored locally on your machine yet, and it is not being streamed from it's location on your email server.  When you try to open the video from there with Windows Media Player, WMP attempts to stream it from this location and fails, since WMP is designed to buffer and stream media when it is not local.

You need to save it locally first.